# created by innerHTML tag is not working

Tags: object, html-lists

I tried to get ID that is created by innerHTML on html li tag. But it always show me 
[object HTMLUListElement] after I created by innerHTML. Here is code created by innerHTML

`<script type="text/javascript">
...
document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML='<ul><li id="312">123</li></ul>';
...
</script>`

But when I create `<ul><li id="312">123</li></ul>` on body then I can get ID. NO PROBLEM. But when I use innerHTML as first above code to create some li with id. I cannot get ID from li.

What is difference between innerHTML created html and original created html.

How can I get innerHTML created html's li id.

Looking forward your responses.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs cannot start with a number.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried to create id by text . STILL SAME ERROR. document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML='<ul><li id="abc">123</li></ul>';